# Why Spring Batch Admin Console takes time to refresh launch page even after job is completed?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have launched a job through spring batch console UI. After the job completion in summary page, job takes only 10 secs to complete but to actually refresh and make the page ready for launching of next job console takes another 30 to 40 secs.

I was curious to know why it happens and how have to reduce this refresh time of page?

P.S: I am new to Spring Batch Admin Console

Answer (score 0):

Probably an Indexing problem. See core SpringBatch tables an create and index on DB.